# Images not found when using load-balancer, mod_pagespeed, https and mounted disks

Tags: apache, https, load-balancing, lamp, mod-pagespeed

I've been having a problem since i installed mod_pagespeed across our LAMP servers and i can't seem to find an answer to it

**Set-up:**

- Load balancer across 4 LAMP servers
- Mixture of http and https pages
- Product images are shared amongst the servers through a mounted disk (/mnt/media_images/)
- Apache Alias set up:

  ```
  Alias /images/media /mnt/media_images
  ```

  (i.e. **www.example.com/images/media/test.jpg** located on the server at **/mnt/media_images/test.jpg**)
- mod_pagespeed installed on all servers with exact same config:

```
    ModPagespeed on
    ModPagespeedRespectXForwardedProto on
    ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain "http://localhost" "http://www.example.com"
    ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain "http://localhost" "https://www.example.com"
    ModPagespeedMaxInlinedPreviewImagesIndex 20
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments,collapse_whitespace,combine_javascript,insert_dns_prefetch,defer_javascript,insert_image_dimensions,lazyload_images
```

**The Problem:**

mod_pagespeed optimises all images on **http** fine, rewriting filenames and fetching them no problem, i.e.:

- http://www.example.com/images/layout/example1.jpg to http://www.example.com/images/layout/example1.jpg.pagespeed.ce.Sh5dWv3czL.jpg
- http://www.example.com/images/media/example2.jpg to http://www.example.com/images/media/example2.jpg.pagespeed.ce.Sh5dWv3czL.jpg

On **https** all non-product images work fine just like on http, i.e.:

- https://www.example.com/images/layout/example1.jpg to https://www.example.com/images/layout/example1.jpg.pagespeed.ce.Sh5dWv3czL.jpg

...but the product images don't work. The filenames are re-written, but visiting these rewritten filenames return 404s. If you take the rewritten filename and simply change https:// to http:// the image is then returned.

I've tested it on a non load-balanced set up and that seemed to work, so the problem seems to be the combination of a load-balancer with https and an alias pointing to the mounted disk.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the cases as running an instance behind a load balancer then it better to use

```
ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain origin_to_fetch_from origin_specified_in_html
```

Code that restrictions in the sites available conf file for the apache2 and give it a try.